# How to make an element move up with the keyboard on android (HTML 5 app)

Tags: android, css

I want to make my text field that I've fixed to the bottom of the screen move up with the keyboard, basically making it stick to the keyboard.
[This is how it looks without the keyboard, the element I want to move up with the keyboard is the footer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHAiz.png) 
When the keyboard pops-up it now goes over the input field, so you can't see what your typing. How could I fix this? Thanks in advace!

The html for this part:

```
    <footer class="mdl-shadow--8dp">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="addItemDescription">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="addItemDescription">What do I need to do?</label>
        </div>
        <button id="addItemButton" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <img class="material-icons" src="./res/material_icons/ic_add_white_24px.svg"></img>
        </button>
    </footer>
```

And the CSS:

```
    footer{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 700;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.mdl-textfield__label{
    color: #4c4c4c;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.mdl-textfield__label:after{
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

.mdl-button--fab.mdl-button--colored {
    background:  #778f9b;
}

.mdl-button--fab.mdl-button--colored:hover {
    background:  #8d8d8d ;
}

#addItemButton{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -45px;
}
```

Comment: You are working through android native? or can you add values in manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with **jQuery**, get the <**input**> tag's **offset().top** value then set document scroll position using **scrollTop()**

```
var $htmlOrBody = $('html, body'), // scrollTop works on <body> for some browsers, <html> for others
scrollTopPadding = 8;

$('input').focus(function() {
// get input tag's offset top position
var textareaTop = $(this).offset().top;
// scroll to the textarea
$htmlOrBody.scrollTop(textareaTop - scrollTopPadding);

// OR  To add animation for smooth scrolling, use this. 
//$htmlOrBody.animate({ scrollTop: textareaTop - scrollTopPadding }, 200);

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. It does scroll in the item list, but it doesn't move the footer and it also scrolls when there's no keyboard.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzKLcVvi2cgTRDBCQ1F5Skc5Vms I don't know what you mean with marking, but on the right you can see how it looks before clicking on the input and on the left you can see the result of clicking of the input.

Comment: So I have one more suggestion. Can you add a div below the textField and give it a static height of 60px as you focus on the textField. Also hide it when not in focus. This can be a hot fix. By the time I'll look for more good possible solution.

Comment: Note that the position of the footer is fixed, so adding a static element below it won't effect it, altough I do really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If found a method that works, it's not really perfect, but it works pretty good. It works like this: run a function when the input is clicked that checks if the device is a phone and than add 50vh to the padding-bottom of the footer. There's also an function  that gets run when the input is getting blurred, this function resets the padding.

The css looks like this:

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 700;
    text-align: center;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

The JS (with a bit of jquery) looks like this:

```
document.querySelector(DOM.description).addEventListener('click', input);
document.querySelector(DOM.description).addEventListener('blur', uniput);

var input = function(){
        if(document.querySelector(DOM.description) === document.activeElement){
            console.log('focused');

            if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                $('footer').css({'padding-bottom': '50vh'})
            }
    }
};

var uniput = function(){
    $('footer').css({'padding-bottom': '1rem'})
    }
```

It's not to difficult, but it took some time to find out if there was a better way to it, but this actually works really nicely.